# Getting the error: "! Argument of \MT@res@a has an extra }."

Tags: errors, document-classes, acm

I'm writing a submission for an ACM conference,  using the ACM's `acm_proc_article-sp` document class. Now, this is a document I transitioned from another document class, so the LaTeX in the body of this paper is pretty sound. Still, I'm getting error message:

```
> ! Argument of \MT@res@a has an
> extra }.
```

In a place with no funny business taking place (no figures, no equations, just text and section/subsection/etc headers.)

What could be triggering this?

**Edit:** I can no longer reproduce this myself, but this *is* an issue, as we can tell from the comments. If you read this question when encountering the same problem yourself - please ask a new question, even if it's somewhat of a dupe, since this one is closed. And - try harder than I did to post a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: I guess `an extra }`.

Comment: You are a member for over 4 years, have asked 59 questions yourself and answered almost the same amount of answers. You should know that it is impossible to help with the error message. And by the way, the comment is completely fine for *What could be triggering this?*

Comment: the error message hints at a problem related to `microtype`, but without an example impossible to solve

Comment: Unfortunately I've had trouble creating a MWE, so perhaps I should delete this. On the other hand, someone just upvoted, so...

Comment: I started getting this message when I started using the Cormorant Garamond font with XeLaTeX and redefining titles via `titlesec`. I had still loaded `microtype` so disabling it resolved the problem as suggested @Robert's comment.  But it also was resolved by _either_ changing the font back to default _or_ by disabling `titlesec`.  I was trying to figure out how to reproduce the problem but have been unable to so far. But maybe my observations help someone in the future.

Comment: This might be a problem with special characters in your .bib file. My problem was solved thanks to [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300395/biber-2-4-microtype-and-special-characters/300397#comment727430_300395), which suggested adding`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio: Would you mind expanding this into an answer? Perhaps with a before/after example? As you can see I can't really do it myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, since the question was closed, I can't post an answer either.

Comment: I'm getting it if I use `\pagenumbering{roman}`. I'm using the `article` class. I'm already using T1 and UTF8 and Biblatex has no trouble with my code if I stick to `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

Comment: I get this error in the ACM template if I include `\{` in the email command.  E.g.: `\email{\{foo\}}`. I have not yet found a solution.

Comment: If you put anything that starts with '\' in `\email{}` causes this problem.

Comment: In my case, this was indeed before the garbage inside `email` which was put there by the lhs2TeX tool. The tool reserves `@` as a start of inline code, so it damaged the email address. Easy fix is to escape by using `@@` in the address.

Comment: I am getting the same problem with a class of my own after a MikTeX update one day ago. It was not happening before the update. My class is too complicated to provide now an MWE and I absolutely need to explore this issue further before posting a question, but I do think that this topic deserves attention and getting the post closed was not the best thing to do about it.

Comment: I've just had this problem and commenting out the microtype package fixed it. But then after one succseful compile, I could use microtype again and it compiled fine

Comment: @innisfree: Then, perhaps you could try minimizing the document manifesting the issue, and filing a bug report with the microtype maintainer(s)? If you do so, please post an answer here. Of course, for me, this was a few years ago by now...

Comment: Alright, let me find some time

Comment: argh, please could someone reopen this so I can answer it?

Comment: @innisfree I don't think that this a valid answer. There is absolutly no proof that what worked for you worked also for the original problem. The error message is a quite generic error (from microtype as has already been mentioned earlier) and can happen in various situations.

Comment: @innisfree the question has been reopened.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio: The question is now open in case you want to post an answer.

Comment: Thank you, @einpoklum, will do. Might help someone see it better. I'll try expanding it a bit, though I don't have LaTeX available right now.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a problem with special characters (e.g. accents) in your .bib file. My problem was solved thanks to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300395/biber-2-4-microtype-and-special-characters/300397#comment727430_300395), which suggested simply adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble of the `.tex` document.

Comment: I can no longer reproduce the issue - after 4 years I don't have those files the way I had them then - but I hope this helps others who may encounter the same error. So, not voting, but thanks.

Comment: This did not work for me, but in my case I had a `³` in a URL in my bibliography, which I converted to a regular `3` and thankfully the URL still worked. In addition, this was not an issue when using scrreport, but only when using the journal's official template for some reason.