# Biber 2.4, microtype, and special characters

Tags: biblatex, biber, microtype

I just performed an update of all packages in my `texlive` distribution (2015) and now I'm having trouble combining `biber`+`biblatex` with the `microtype` package.

The error seems to arise only when using 'special' characters in the `bib` file, and only when I ask to print the bibliography. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{renyi1970,
  author = {R\'enyi, Alfr\'ed},
  location = {San Francisco},
  publisher = {Holden-Day},
  title = {Foundations of Probability},
  year = {1970},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{renyi1970}

    \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

The error message I get starts like so:

```
! Argument of \MT@res@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.23 

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
##1,\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ,##2##3\@nnil {\ifx ##2\@empty \MT@inlist@false \else \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \MT@res@a was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.23
```

The problem goes away if I remove the `\printbibliography` command, even if I use the `authoryear` citation style, so that the diacritics alone aren't generating the problem. That is, the following compiles as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{renyi1970,
  author = {R\'enyi, Alfr\'ed},
  location = {San Francisco},
  publisher = {Holden-Day},
  title = {Foundations of Probability},
  year = {1970},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{renyi1970}


\end{document}
```

The error seems to have something to do with the interaction between `microtype` and `biber`, since it doesn't arise with just one of them (I tried `microtype` with `bibtex` as backend for `biblatex` and it worked just fine; I also tried `biber` without `microtype` and it also worked just fine).

I gather `microtype` hasn't been updated since 2013, so I'm assuming the problem was introduced with the newer version of `biber` (2.4) or with the newer version of `biblatex` (3.3).

Comment: It is `biblatex` 3.3. `Biber has only version `2.4`.

Comment: I get no error if I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Hmm. Neither do I. Why would that be? This hadn't been an issue up until today.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd say this is a bug in `biblatex`:

In `biblatex_.sty` (which is the non-legacy version that is used with `biber`), we find right at the beginning:

```
% Tests for emptiness, regardless whether the arg is macro or literal
% Expand everything and test as string
\def\ifempty#1{%
  \edef\z{#1}%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\z}}
```

Now, `\edef`'ing user input is something that should never be done, period.

The OP's minimal example works for me if I replace `\edef` with `\protected@edef` (which is latex's "user-safe" version of `\edef`), but I cannot foresee which other consequences this might have.

Comment: +1. This move seems to have been introduced in the most recent update to version 3.3 because `biblatex2.sty` (precursor to `biblatex_.sty`) does not have this test.

Comment: This test has already been changed in the dev version (I'd spotted much the same 'from first principles').

Comment: @JosephWright Mhhh, things have been changed a bit to use `\pdfstrcmp`. With the newest dev version from github I can still reproduce the issue.

Comment: +10 (if I could give 10). This bug killed the processing of a very large document and cost me much time until now. With your replacement, everything seems to work fine. :-)

Comment: +10 to you as well. Thank you *very much* for taking the time to look into this and saving my day. (Terrible things were about to happen).

Answer (score 8):

This was, due to a biblatex change. I was trying to insulate users as much as possible from the namepart changes but this isn't really feasible because of this sort of consequence. As mentioned, the problem doesn't exist if you use fontenc which I assume you should be doing anyway. However, I have changed the problematic test in biblatex 3.4 on DEV and the problem no longer occurs.

Answer (score 7):

I get no error if I just add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. It's not really clear where `microtype` chokes when the encoding is OT1.

`biblatex 2016/03/03 v3.3` and `biber version: 2.4`

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{renyi1970,
  author = {R\'enyi, Alfr\'ed},
  location = {San Francisco},
  publisher = {Holden-Day},
  title = {Foundations of Probability},
  year = {1970},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{microtype}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{renyi1970}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not convinced. I always get errors with command forms in `.bib` files and I always use `T1` and `inputenc` with `utf8`. I'm just so used to it that I do the corrections to the `.bib` without thinking about it even as an error any more. (Existing entries only cause issues if I cite them and I only correct them if they cause problems or I happen to feel like it, which isn't often.)

Comment: @cfr On my machine the example above runs without errors.

Comment: I think I use curly brackets around something. Maybe that's the difference.

Comment: `{\'e}`, for example. Or maybe they've actually fixed it in the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Run `biber` with

```
biber --output-safechars <file>
```

However, it makes more sense to write

```
author = {Rényi, Alfréd},
```

and using `lualatex` or at least `

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

for `pdflatex`

Comment: @egreg: I can compile  with accented characters and loading option `utf8` for `inputenc`…

Comment: The second suggestion doesn't help me. I will try running `biber` with the option you mention and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Run with accented characters for the .bib file. Don't forget `biber` understands `utf8`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{renyi1970,
  author = {Rényi, Alfred},
  location = {San Francisco},
  publisher = {Holden-Day},
  title = {Foundations of Probability},
  year = {1970},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{renyi1970}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't help me to use `utf8`. Do you get the error if you use `\'e` etc. but not if you use `é`?

Comment: I get exactly the same error as the OP, with this example.

Comment: @apc: Correct. I must use the `é` form to get no error. Of course this demonstrates there is a problem between microtype and biblatex, but apparently, writing accented letters is a workaround.

Comment: With `\'e` or `é` it's exactly the same.

Comment: And loading `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} `?

Comment: @egreg This problem isn't new, though, is it? I didn't know `microtype` was involved, but I have got errors if I use macros for accented characters in `.bib` files for ages. Using the actual character avoids the problem. [I'm just saying this to make clear that it is not due to the update to Biber/Biblatex. I always use `microtype`.]

Comment: @Bernard Of course, with `inputenc` for `é`. The same as with `\'e`, which is not surprising, as `é` gets translated into `\'e`.

Comment: @cfr What errors did you get exactly with accented letters? Normally, `biblatex` and Biber are quite good in dealing with them. Maybe we can investigate that in more detail.